# Why isn't an error being displayed upon the completion of a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

When in a bash script I refer to a non-existent file, the script throws an error and terminates due to this error.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# to automatically terminate the script upon error
set -e

# read from the file
read < file

# not executed because there was an error during reading
echo no-continue
```

The terminal displays:

```
./test: line 5: file: No such file or directory
```

However, when I refer to an empty file, the script also terminates due to an error but does not output any error. Why?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# to automatically terminate the script upon error
set -e

# create a file
touch file
# read from the file
read < file

# not executed because there was an error during reading
echo no-continue
```

Nothing is displayed in the terminal. Why doesn't it output the error to the terminal?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to create a file to demonstrate this, just use `read < /dev/null`.

Comment: Because *file* exist, so there is no error, but `read` throw a *(silent) error* because it can't read anything. At @Barmar suggest, you could test: `if read _ </dev/null;then echo success;else echo fail;fi`

Comment: This is how `read` is designed: Using an empty file with `read` is not an **error**, but `read` sets exit code 1, and since you are using the - IMHO silly - `set -e`, your program exits.

Answer (score 3):

It's not considered an error to read at the end of an input stream, it's the normal condition when you reach EOF. `read` returns a non-zero exit status so the caller can detect this condition, but it doesn't print an error message.

This is so you can write loops that read a file until EOF.

```
while read -r line; do
    # do stuff
done < file
```

If it printed an error message, every loop like this would show the error.

Comment: There are lots of conditions that aren't really errors, but aren't success either, like `grep` not finding any matches to the specified pattern, `find` not finding any matching files, or even a `(( ))` arithmetic expression evaluating to zero. These will generally give a nonzero exit status (so `set -e` will treat them as fatal errors), but no error message. This is one of many reasons `set -e` is problematic; see [BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: Gordon Davisson Thank you

Comment: @GordonDavisson Right. `grep` also uses different non-zero exit codes for expected failures like "match not found" and real errors like "file not found".